# OpenGL exponential shadow mapping (ESM) artifact

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to implement exponential shadow mapping (ESM) into my rendering engine but I'm facing some problems: I can get to see some shadows only if the exponential multiplier is less than 0, and the image becomes very dark.

I was already using Variance Shadow Maps, so I adapted my code to use ESM.

I've changed the fragment shader used to compute the shadow map like this:

```
#version 150 core

uniform float Exponential;    // Exponential multiplier term of the ESM equation

out float FragColor;

float map_01(float x, float v0, float v1)
{
    return (x - v0) / (v1 - v0);
}

void main()
{
    float depthDivisor = (1.0 / gl_FragCoord.z);
    float mappedDivisor = map_01(depthDivisor, 0.1f, 20.0f);    // Since my light is a directional light I force the near and far planes to 0.1 and 20.0
    FragColor = exp(Exponential * mappedDivisor);

    // VSM  float depth = gl_FragCoord.z;
    // VSM  float dx = dFdx(depth);
    // VSM  float dy = dFdy(depth);
    // VSM  float moment2 = depth * depth + 0.25 * (dx * dx + dy * dy);
    // VSM  FragColor = vec4(depth, moment2, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I've kept the same vertex shader for the shadow map:

```
in vec3 _position;

uniform mat4 ProjectionViewMatrix;   // Projection-View matrix of the light

layout(std140) uniform MOD
{
    mat4 AModelMatrix[20];
};

void main()
{
    gl_Position = ProjectionViewMatrix * AModelMatrix[gl_InstanceID] * vec4(_position, 1.0);
}
```

And I've changed the my directional light fragment shader to become like this:

```
uniform mat4 InverseProjectionViewMatrix; // Inverse of the camera projection-view matrix
uniform float Exponential;                // Exponential multiplier term of the ESM equation (same as shadow map fragment shader)
uniform mat4 ProjectionViewMatrix;        // Light projection view matrix

void main()
{
     vec3 genPos    = vec3((gl_FragCoord.x * InverseScreenSize.x), (gl_FragCoord.y * InverseScreenSize.y), 0.0f);
     genPos.z       = texture(PrepassBuffer_DepthMap, genPos.xy).r;

     vec4 clip          = InverseProjectionViewMatrix * vec4(genPos * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f);
     vec3 pos           = clip.xyz / clip.w;

     vec4 shadowCoord   = ProjectionViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0f);
     shadowCoord        /= shadowCoord.w;
     shadowCoord.xyz    = shadowCoord.xyz * vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f) + vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

     float occluder = texture(DILShadowMap, shadowCoord.xy).r;
     float reciever = map_01(shadowCoord.z, 0.1f, 20.0f);
     float shadowAmount = saturate(occluder * exp(-Exponential * reciever));
     ...
}
```

A couple of images to show the problem.

This is the result I get with Exponential set to 1.0 (no shadows at all):
[image]

This is the result I get with Exponential set to -30.0 (starting to see some shadows):
[image]

This is the result I get with the exact same coputations of the position (same vertex shaders basically) but with the variance shadow maps equation:
[image]

The only things I've changed from the algorithm I've found are these two lines in the shadow map fragment shader and in the directional light fragment shader:

```
// Shadow map fragment shader
float depthDivisor = (1.0 / gl_FragCoord.z); // <- changed gl_FragCoord.z (originally was gl_FragCoord.w)

// Directional light fragment shader
float reciever = map_01(shadowCoord.z, 0.1f, 20.0f); // <- changed shadowCoord.z (originally was shadowCoord.w)
```

I've made these two changes because the W component was always 1.0, and it didn't seem correct to me to use W when the depth is stored into the Z component.

Comment: Within your lighting system, are you taking into consideration any kind of normal data for your models?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by normal data? Do you mean my model's meshes normals?

Comment: Yes, the normals that are calculated either for each vertex or for each triangle face within the mesh. The normal, tangents, bi-tangents that are used in lighting calculations to display the proper lighting and shadow effects.

Comment: Well, I use the normals of each vertex of the mesh and store them into one texture during my first pass of the deferred shader. At the moment I don't use the tangents and bitangents since I'm not doing any normal mapping.